# What does the ち mean in this situation?

Tags: usage

Why is Ms. Kobayashi's Dragon Maid written as 小林さんちのメイドラゴン instead of 小林さんのメイドラゴン? I'm still new to Japanese and I don't understand what the ち is for in the title. Can it be written either way? I can't find any other pages online that explain it. When an I supposed to use it?